# How to make some CSS properties work with IE browser

Tags: css

I am using IE browser version 10, Chrome browser version 34 and FireFox browser version 28.  I have the following CSS class that works well with Chrome and FireFox browsers; the class (named ".container") makes HTML elements stretch whole window screen horizontally as expected. But with IE, the class does not work; all HTML elements shrink toward the center of the window screen horizontally.  How can I update the ".container" class so it also works with IE?  Thank you in advance.

```
.container {
    max-width:initial !important;
    width: initial !important;
    min-width:1000px;
}
```

Sample using of the class:

```
<div class="container">
   ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`min-width` and `max-width` are calculated based on provided `width` value. Here you state `width:initial` which is **not a valid amount** for such calculations to occur.

You need to specify a unit based number for `width` in order to correctly define the parameters for your expected behaviour.

**[`min-width` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width)**

> The min-width CSS property is used to set the minimum width of a given
>   element. It prevents the used **value of the width** property from
>   becoming smaller than the value specified for min-width.

[**More on Width from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)

To use `min-width` and `max-width`, these values as well as `width` need to be set to numeric units.

Answer (score 0):

`initial` is not supported by IE10

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/initial

why not use auto?